# Laravel 5.2 multiple email sending. Get email address in view

Tags: php, laravel, email, swiftmailer

How to get the actually/current email address in the 'emails.subscribed' view?
Here is my code:

```
Mail::send('emails.subscribed', $data, function($message) use ($subject,$recievers,$meta) {
    foreach ($recievers as $email) {
        $message->bcc($email,$email);
        $message->email = $email;
    }
});
```

And the view I need to get the current email address (not the whole email array just only the current):
`{{$somehow->email}}`

Comment: To accomplish this, I would suggest creating the whole Mail fascade in the foreach loop and pass through the current email, because in your case, the view should be built depending on the individual receipents.

Comment: So you can say: foreach(){ Mail::send() }
Not too slow this method if you has many recipients?

Comment: Yes, you should do this indeed. And yes, it could be slow, but the view has to be created individually anyway, so I think its the best option after all. Good luck!

Comment: Understood.
I was hoping that there is another way. So I accept @Adiasz response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send emails one by one, not all in bcc, then you can easily change email view:

```
$recipients = [ ["name" => "John", "email" => "john@john.com"], ["name" => "Doe", "email" => "doe@doe.com"] ];

$subject = 'subject';
$meta = 'meta';

foreach($recipients as $recipient) {
    // here you declare variables accesable in view file
    $dataToPassToEmailView = [];
    // **key** of this table is variable **name in view**
    $dataToPassToEmailView['recipient'] = $recipient;

    Mail::send('emails.subscribed', $dataToPassToEmailView, function($message) use ($subject, $recipient, $meta) {
        $message->to($recipient['email'], $recipient['name']);
        $message->subject($subject);
    });
}
```

view emails.subscribed.blade.php:

```
Email: {{ $recipient['email'] }}
Name: {{ $recipient['name'] }}
```